# How can we execute the test plan in JMeter application with internal server port

Tags: jmeter

How can we execute the test plan in JMeter application with internal server. Example: http://122.175.62.210:7575/

I need the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Given the operating system is capable of connecting to the "internal" server JMeter should be able to do it as well, the system under test doesn't have to be available over the Internet.

If you can connect to the "internal" server from the machine(s) you intend to run JMeter on using [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or equivalent - JMeter will be able to connect as well. Otherwise you might need to set up a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) connection.

So just configure [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices)) accordingly and that would be it:

[image]